# Passing Multiple Arguments to a Custom Event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, event-handling

According to the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments) - I linked to the relevant page - I can emit a custom event together with a value by typing `<ChildComponent @click="$emit('myEvent', 1)" />` and, if the event handler on the parent component is a method, this value will be passed as its argument. But what if I want to pass another argument to the handler when calling it in the parent component? Can I simply write `<ParentComponent @myEvent="eventHandler(2)" />` and then have the function accept two arguments, like this?

```js
function eventHandler(childArgument, parentArgument) {
  // I want to have access to the value 1 from the child and the value 2 from the parent component here.
  // If I do it like this, will childArgument contain the 1 and parentArgument the 2?
}
```

And if this doesn't work, how would I have to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I just recently did this in my project.
In your example of a ChildComponent and ParentComponent you can have

`<ChildComponent @click="$emit('myEvent', 1)" />`

`<ParentComponent @myEvent="eventHandler(2, ...arguments)" />`

Then your eventHandler would look like this

`function eventHandler(parentArgument, childArgument) { ... }`

You can probably change the ordering as you wish but this worked for me. Also just a side note I believe it's recommended to use kebab-case for the html elements.